# Hystrix Configuration clarification: metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds

Tags: hystrix

I am trying to understand how the metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds and metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets work together.

If I have the following configuration:

```
circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=20
circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=50
metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds=10000
metrics.rollingStats.numBuckets=10
```

To me this means:
1) I need a min of 20 request in my window before a decision will be made
2) At or more than 50% of the requests will need to fail for the breaker to open

But how does the number of buckets come into play?  Is the requestVolumeThreshHold and error threshold per bucket? I am trying to understand if/how the buckets are used in determining to trip the breaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question by creating a simple app that tests the circuit breaker.

The equation to determine when to open the circuit uses request volume threshold, error threshold percentage during the entire rolling stats timeInMilliseconds window.  The buckets are only used for how/when the rolling window is updated.